# How to remove surface mold on shower walls and ceilings?

Tags: bathroom, painting, cleaning, mold, plaster

I'll be doing a small bathroom remodel on a VERY old house which mainly includes installing bathroom fan and a full paint job as the main tasks.  On first walk through, I noticed that the house has visible black mold on the plaster walls and ceiling (I'm assuming this is plaster too...) inside of the combination bath/shower.

Along with the visible mold, the paint on those surfaces is deteriorating and badly peeling (which is the original reason I was called for painting).

I explained to the homeowner that since the original bathroom had no exhaust fan or proper venting, this was the perfect condition for moisture to build and mold to grow, so we added bathroom fan as a requirement.  I said I would research ways to remove the mold and properly prepare the surfaces before painting.

I am thinking:

1. Physically scrape away all peeling paint, and dispose.
2. Pre-spray all areas with vinager, and let set for 1 hour.
3. Deep scrub all areas w/ Borax or TPS.
4. Fully DRY for 24 hours.
5. Prime with KILZ.
6. Paint.

Any feedback on this plan?  Also -- anything special I need to do since the walls are PLASTER and not regular drywall?

Comment: Personally I’d use a strong bleach and water solution instead of vinegar, but some websites do list vinegar as a solution for mold removal.

Comment: Chlorine bleach will kill mold better than vinegar and will bleach out the discoloration. Wear old clothes to use chlorine bleach. Spray it on is easiest, but if you don't have a sprayer then dab it on with a hand mop. Use neoprene or rubber gloves because it will run down the handle of the mop and onto you hand and arm. Let sit to kill the mold for at least 4 hr and then rinse off with a hand held the shower head.  Do not add any vinegar over the chlorine bleach (before it is rinsed off) because it can evolve dangerous amounts of chlorine gas.

Comment: Redo with bleach if necessary and let dry. Scrape loose paint, prime with Kilz and paint.

Comment: You could scrape loose paint before using the bleach and then re-scrape after since  bleaching may loosen some paint. No need to bleach paint which is going to be scraped off.

Comment: Purchase a 1-gal plastic garden sprayer to apply bleach. It will make the job so much easier and faster. Mix bleach 1/2 cup to 1 cup per gallon of water. Wear glasses and be careful you don't get too much inhalation exposure.

Comment: Hey @JimStewart - thanks for the tips.  Maybe you can combine your answers into 1 official answer and I'll mark it answered.  Thanks!

Comment: i should point out that both OSHA and EPA have stopped recommending bleach for mold remediation. it can hide the problem, it can feed water (once the chlorine quickly evaporates) to deep spores/mycellium, and it's never been recommended for anything porous, like drywall.

Comment: @dandavis So would you recommend the TPS/Borax route or a more mold specific off-the-shelf cleaner?

Comment: tbh, i would probably still bleach it (i'm a rebel and hey, it makes it LOOK better), but i would also use a boric acid solution that i SOAKED the offending area with, probably multiple times to make sure it can't come back. Bleach can treat the symptoms but leave ripe conditions under the surface, and it dries out quickly; leaving no protection once dry. Boric acid doesn't evaporate, so it _keeps_ the crevices and insides mold-free.